# I cant launch antivirus

Tags: location

I have installed clamAV on my ubuntu operating system, what should I do to run it?
I have tried to search it but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have Clamtk installed.  ClamTk is an easy to use graphical front-end for Clam Antivirus.  If not just install it using synaptic, or use `sudo apt get install clamtk` in terminal, then Search for it in Dash, search for clamtk, or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
clamtk
```

Comment: +1. ClamAV is a command-line tool that can't be found in the menus. Also, if you're using KDE Plasma or Kubuntu, there may be a better ClamAV frontend than ClamTk for KDE Plasma.

Comment: `ClamAV` is the Terminal command

Answer (score 0):

To locate a software there are several ways:

1. Using launcher
   Press <kbd>Super</kbd> key (aka Windows) and type `clamAV`.
2. Using `locate` command (also `whereis`)
   Open terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
   Type `locate clamav`.
3. Hunt through desktop files
   Go to `/usr/share/applications`
4. Hunt through executable files
   Go to `/usr/bin`